# I want to leave only one word with the same value in the DataFrame and delete the rest

Tags: csv

ex)

| en | ko |
| --- | --- |
| acrania | a |
| acrania | b |
| acrania | c |
| acrania | d |

=>

| en | ko |
| --- | --- |
| acrania | a |

There are about 400,000 word pairs, so it is difficult to refine them one by one. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'en': ['acrania', 'acrania', 'acrania', 'acrania'], 'ko': ['a', 'b', 'c', "d"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='en', keep="first")
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```